# Align a button to a table with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get these buttons to be even with my table, but it isn't working very well, they just sit at the bottom.  For simplicity the styles are inline and the table is static (in reality this table is being dynamically populated with images).

```
<button id="lftArrow">&laquo;</button>
<table style="display:inline-table;border:0px;height:120px;">
  <tr id="pictureSetDisplay" name="pictureSetDisplay">
    <td>some picture</td>
    <td>some picture</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="rgtArrow">&raquo;</button>
```

Any ideas what type of style I should apply to the buttons to get them to be sitting in the vertical middle of the table?

Comment: In this fiddle the buttons are middle aligned, this isn't the result you're expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/hBZDT/

Comment: I mean vertically, as in they are sitting in the middle of the table height (table height / 2).  In said fiddle they are not.

Comment: I just checked the fiddle with Google Chrome and indeed the buttons were sitting in the bottom. In Firefox they were at the middle. Please see my answer for a CSS only way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the buttons as well inside a table - an outer table. But yes, this will involve one more table.

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FYV3m/3/

```
<table border="1"><tr>
  <td valign="middle">
    <button id="lftArrow" style="height:120px">&laquo;</button>
  </td><td valign="middle">
    <table style="display:inline-table;border:0px;height:120px;">
      <tr id="pictureSetDisplay" name="pictureSetDisplay">
        <td>some picture</td>
        <td>some picture</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td><td valign="middle">
    <button id="rgtArrow" style="height: 120px">&raquo;</button>
  </td>
</tr></table>
```

You can remove the height style from the button (or CSS) as needed.

Comment: I don't mind using another table, although the question was intended to see if this was plausible in css.  HOWEVER, I actually like the look of the larger buttons +1, *accepted*

Answer (score 1):

Set `vertical-align: middle` on the table itself, like shown in here: http://jsfiddle.net/hBZDT/1/

```
<button id="lftArrow">&laquo;</button>
<table style="vertical-align: middle; display:inline-table;border:solid 1px;height:120px;">
  <tr id="pictureSetDisplay" name="pictureSetDisplay">
    <td>some picture</td>
    <td>some picture</td>
    <td>some picture</td>
    <td>some picture</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="rgtArrow">&raquo;</button>
```

Although possible, please avoid using HTML tables to layout elements on your website.

Comment: Thank you TomS, this is a good solution and answers my original question - I have already accepted another answer though.  I appreciate the conciseness of your css, but it turns out for other reasons adding the extra table was required.  In my opinion, tables are often the best way to implement layout design structure, and are very widely used.  Please try to open this point as a discussion if you wish to make that point.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with **margin:auto**

http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Comment: Sorry, but that is horizontal alignment, I am talking about vertical alignment, and the actual size of the [HtmlObject] of the <button> is very small so aligning via margin will not actually change anything.